# Why is it "wherever" instead of "whereever"?

Tags: orthography, is-it-a-rule, compound-words

The popular question words *how*, *when*, *what*, *why*, *which* and some more all have their accompanying word ending in *-ever*, like *however* and *whatever*.

It seems to me that the word *wherever* is somewhat inconsistent in this context, as it omits one *e* — either the last letter of *where* or the first letter of *ever*.

Is the spelling of *wherever* a simple exception, or is there a (probably not limited to these question words and the *-ever* ending) rule that can help me to figure out when to omit a vowel without googling for it?

Comment: Because language is primarily spoken, and the written form attempts to capture it (not always very effectively). The word _where_ ends with an /r/ sound, not a vowel, so _wherever_ plonks _ever_ on the end of that. The silent 'e' is fairly pointless anyway, but is hardly ever written in the middle of words, and never before another vowel.

Comment: @ColinFine Your “and never before another vowel” thing doesn’t hold in lawyerese, wherein can be found no few such annoyances as just previously demonstrated.

Comment: @tchrist: true. I overspoke.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is generally called the *[silent e rule](http://www.resourceroom.net/readspell/silentedrop.asp)*:

*Suffix addition: dropping silent e*

> - The silent e rule is more consistent than the doubling rule. The principle: since the silent e's "job" is to change a vowel sound, if there is another vowel to take its place, the e can go away.
> - Therefore, if the suffix begins with a vowel, you drop the e.
> - It doesn't matter how many syllables there are, or what the vowel coming before the silent e sounds like, or whether there are two consonants ("wasting" drops the e, too).
> - There are some exceptions -- when you need to keep the e for some other purpose, such as making a c or g say /s/ or /j/, as in "courageous."

Source: www.resourceroom.net

Answer (score 6):

As a gross general rule of thumb, word final single 'e' gets deleted before suffixes beginning with vowels, especially grammatical suffixes. So we don't have:

- liveing
- liveed
- giveer
- blueish
- trueer
- trueest
- sizees

Instead we get:

- living
- lived
- giver
- bluish
- truest
- sizes

*Wherever* seems to fit this rule of thumb.

*Hope this is helpful!*

Comment: Note that the fairly common "moreover" and "whereupon" defy this rule of thumb.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Indeed, that's true! I  have a feeling that's because these are proper compounds of prepositions, whereas *ever* is a genuine grammatical suffix, you can stick it on just about any *wh-* word.

Answer (score 4):

The thing you need to remember about the word *wherever* is that **it used to be two words**, and began life that way. For quite a while it was written that way, too, but then it started getting hyphenated.  When finally the hyphen itself was lost, it made no sense to write with two *e*’s the sound of just one of them.

The OED says:

> Orginally as two words (and so still in sense 1); subsequently often with hyphen, *where-ever* (*where-e’er*), etc.; now always in contracted spelling *wherever* (*where’er*), the final *e* of *where* coalescing with the initial *e* of *ever*.

That last past about “now always in contracted spelling” tells the entire tale of this fully predictable coalescence. The OED elsewhere points out that the very same thing happened to the somewhat uncommonly seen *whosever*, where again it came from *whose* + *ever*, but lost one *e* upon contraction.

However, the now-archaic *whosesoever* with its infix *-so-* was enough to preserve the final *e* of *whose*.  But that flavor of the word is exceedingly rare.   Is isn’t clear how it might have further contracted in writing had it seen more use.  Notice that the corresponding *wheresoever* keeps everything, so perhaps it just wouldn’t have.

One more of these oldies that follows the same sort of coalescence is *whencever*, formed from *whence* + *ever* but losing an *e*.  There was once also the conjunction *whilever*, but that’s now considered declassé.

Here’s the full OED list of the related *-ever* words, mostly formed by starting  with *wh*-question words and then adding a piece or two to make a compound word. Notice how those formed with infix *-some-* also lose an *e* upon fusion with a following *ever*. Words that have lost an *-e* are marked in bold below; as you will see, it is **entirely predicable** when this occurs:

- however [adv.]
- howsoever [adv.]
- **howsomever** [adv.]
- whatever [pron. and adj.]
- whatsoever [pron.]
- **whatsomever** [pron.]
- whencesoever [adv.]
- **whencever** [adv.]
- whenever [adv.]
- whensoever [adv.]
- **whensomever** [adv.]
- whereinsoever [adv.]
- wheresoever [adv.]
- **wheresomever** [adv.]
- wheretoever ← whereto
- **wherever** [adv.]
- whethersoever [pron.]
- whichever [adj.]
- whichsoever [pron.]
- **whilever** [conj.] ← while
- whithersoever [adv.]
- whoever [pron.]
- whomever [pron.]
- whomsoever [pron.]
- whosesoever [pron.]
- **whosever** [pron.]
- whosoever [pron.]
- **whosomever** [pron.]
- whyever [adv.]

The list also includes without prejudice words of that formulation which might now be considered archaic, obsolete, or vulgar (read: uneducated), but it does exclude predictable poetic contractions such as *where’er*.

Answer (score 1):

One should add that "ee" is an irritating vowel group if it is not a long /i:/ as in to feel, to see, knee, wheel etc. So it is useful that a final and silent e is omitted when a syllable is added. If we spelled live +ed as liveed you would probably read /li'vi:d/, and then in a second reading you would recognize that the past form of to live is meant.

Answer (score 1):

Summary of some other jobs of **Silent E**

Job #1: Silent E makes the vowel before it *long*, as in **note.**

Job #2: Silent E can make c and g *soft*, as in **race and page.**

Job #3: Silent E keeps u and v from being the last letter in a word, as in **clue and give.**

Job #4: Silent E adds a vowel to words with the Consonant+l-e syllable pattern, as in **handle.**

@Araucaria
=> Where + ever = wherever
   The single 'E' gets deleted before suffixes beginning with vowels